# Backing up system in a way that preserves user accounts

Tags: upgrade, backup, multiple-users

I'll be backing up a deep learning rig for work that has an ancient Ubuntu install on it so I can upgrade it to current, but I need a way to do it that can preserve user accounts in addition to their files and such. A simple network upgrade should more than suffice, but I want to be more than sure that everything is properly backed up first.

My friend alleges that if one just backs up the home folder, reinstalls OS, puts the home folder back, and useradds back users with the same names that it will figure it out, but I don't want to bet on that.

I'm open to pretty much any tools or software so long as it can be exported as a tarball or .zip. Sorry for my ignorance, I'd only ever worked with small home installations with a single user so it wasn't a big deal, as opposed to a potentially massive setup like this.

Comment: Is `/home` a separate partition? Is the `sudo` command in use? `cron` jobs? encrypted `HOME` directories? What packages have been installed? What other software has been installed? How ancient is this Ubuntu "rig"? Which release? Are there backups? Your "friend" oversimplified. At the very least, you must maintain `UID`s, `GID`s, group memberships, etc. What's your proposed upgrade path? Have you read the release notes for each release? What wierd setup do you have and how do you think an upgrade will break it?

Comment: Well my superiors got back to me and they ended up just wanting each user's home backed up separately, which is easily manageable with a bash script. I'd still out of curiosity know if it's possible to back up a Linux installation in a way that you could change OS, but leave the user accounts (minus uninstalled software ofc) intact.